# WatiN editing popup

Tags: watin

I'm trying to edit textfields in popup, it appears and does't close browser.Element(Find.ByText("testas1")).DoubleClick();
But still can't find textfield. Any suggestions what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps if you post a bit more of your code (the watin code and the html/whatever), we might be able to help you more easily.  Also, I'm not entirely sure what your problem is - are you clicking buttons, editing text fields, trying to close a popup, or what?

Comment: I figure it out by using:  browser.HtmlDialogs[0].TextFields[0].TypeText("T"); thnx any way:)

Comment: If you write that out as an answer, and mark it as the correct answer, it might help people with the same problem (That's the generally accepted way of doing things on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser.HtmlDialogs[0].TextFields[0].TypeText("T");